# magnetic field of a rotating ring magnet

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, induction

Can the magnetic field of a rotating ring magnet induce current in a conductor?
Is there a flux linkage between magnetic field of a rotating ring magnet and a conductor?

Comment: Yes, in electric machines for instance. I'm not sure about the meaning of question n°2.

Comment: By the way i didnt understand the 2nd question.

Answer (score 1):

Well it will induce a an electric field in a conductor(take a solenoid and test it with a bulb), but the direction of the current depends on the orientation of the poles as well.
Taking your Ringed Magnet, the poles are likely arranged so that the North Pole is inside and the South pole is inside or vice versa. But, the current is surely to be induced.